# How can I count the number of intersections of lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is my TikZ-Code of intersecting lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.01]
\foreach \line in {-10,-57,-104}
{
    \draw (0,\line) -- ++(438.5,0);
}

\foreach \line in {-160,-241}
{
    \draw (325.5,\line) -- ++(113,0);
}

\foreach \line in {5,50,100,...,300}
{
    \draw[red] (\line,0) -- ++(0,-114);
}       

\foreach \line in {330.5,350,400,433.5}
{
    \draw[red] (\line,0) -- ++(0,-251);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to count the number of intersections (in this case 41) automatically?

Comment: Do you know beforehand which lines are possibly intersecting. In this case we could just use the `intersections` library and ask it to find the intersections between all the red and all the black lines. How should an intersection be counted when three lines meet (and what is your expected error on this)? This example is a very easy one …

Comment: Thanks for the follow up clarification question @Qrrbrbirlbel! There will only be intersections of perpendicular lines, all vertical ones have the same color and all horizontal ones as well. And none of them has to look like a kitten (sorry for the reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this simple case, we can create a path with all red lines and one path with all black lines, then let the `intersections` library can find all intersections between these two lines.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\tikzset{mark options=gray, mark size=+1.5pt, mark=x}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=+.1mm, y=+.1mm]
\draw[name path=blacks]
  foreach \line in {-10, -57, -104}{
    (0, \line) -- +(right:438.5)
  }
  foreach \line in {-160, -241}{
    (325.5, \line) -- +(right:113)
  };
\draw[name path=reds, red]
  foreach \line in {5, 50, 100, ..., 300}{
    (\line, 0) -- +(down:114)
  }
  foreach \line in {330.5, 350, 400, 433.5}{
    (\line, 0) -- +(down:251)
  };
\path[name intersections={of=blacks and reds, name=i, total=\t}]
  plot[samples at={1, ..., \t}] (i-\x)
  node[above right, align=left] at(current bounding box.south west)
  {I've found\\\textcolor{gray}{\t} intersections.};
%%% now \t is lost, either \global it outside the path or
\tikzset{name intersections={of=blacks and reds, total=\T}}
\typeout{I've found \T\space intersections. \t won't work.}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Log

> I've found 41 intersections. \t won't work.

Comment: Awesome, I will try that out in the next days, as I need to modify my more complex code to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know tikz, sorry, but here is a way of doing it in MetaPost/MetaFun. I assume one can do something very similar in tikz. What we do:

- Use some loops to define two (disconnected thanks to `&&`) paths `p` and `q`, one for the horizontal lines and one for the vertical ones.
- Create the intersection points with `p firstintersectionpath q`. This gives a new path consisting of all intersection points.
- Add one to the length of this new path to get the number of points.

```
\startMPpage[offset=1DK]
path p, q, r ;

numeric s ; s := 0.5 ;

p :=
  for i = -10,-57,-104 :
    (0,i) -- (438.5,i) &&
  endfor
  for i = -160, -241 :
    (325.5,i) -- (325.5+113,i) &&
  endfor
  nocycle ;

q :=
  (5,0) -- (5,-114) &&
  for i = 50 step 50 until 300 :
    (i,0) -- (i,-114) &&
  endfor
  for i = 330.5,350,400,433.5 :
    (i,0) -- (i,-251) &&
  endfor
  nocycle ;

p := p scaled s ;
q := q scaled s ;
r := p firstintersectionpath q ;

draw p withcolor darkblue ;
draw q withcolor darkred ;
drawpoints r ;

label.urt("Number of intersections: " & decimal (length r + 1), llcorner currentpicture) ;
\stopMPpage
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Great solution for MetaPost @mickep, but I am unable to translate this to TikZ. Maybe someone can help.